# Rotation of finite subset of the circle group gets close to 1

Tags: complex-numbers

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I can't convince myself if the next statement is either true or false.

Given $\varepsilon >0$ and a finite subset $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ of the circle group $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$, there exists an integer $m\neq 0$ such that $|z_i^m -1|<\varepsilon$ for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

(Any sugestion is appreciated.)

Comment: What has this got to do with group theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let: $$\mathbb{T_{s,k}} = \{e^{t2\pi} |\; t\in [\frac{k-1}{s},\frac{k}{s})  \}\\k\in\{1\dots s\}$$

This denotes a "segment" (arc) of the circle group with the property that any for any two points $z_{1},z_{2} \in \mathbb{T_{s,k}}$ we have $|z_{1}- z_{2}| < \frac{2\pi}{s}$. For any given $s$, the circle group can be divided into exactly $s$ such segments.

By the pigeonhole principle, out of $(s+1)$ elements $z_{1}^1, z_{1}^2 \cdots z_{1}^{s+1}$, at least two, $z_{1}^{p_1}, z_{1}^{p_2}$ with $p_2> p_1$ will fall in the same segment $\mathbb{T^{k}_{s}}$. From this we see $|z_{1}^{p_2} - z_{1}^{p_1}| < \frac{2\pi}{s}$ and $|z_{1}^{p_{2}-p_{1}} - 1|< \frac{2\pi}{s}$

We now generalize this to $n$-tuples of points in $\mathbb{T}^n$. Let: $$(z_1,z_2 \cdots z_{n}) \in \overbrace{\mathbb{T} \oplus \mathbb{T} \dots  \oplus \mathbb{T} }^{n \text{ times}} = \mathbb{T}^n$$

In analogy to the original case, we can split the group into exactly $s^n$ regions of the form:

$$(\mathbb{T_{s,k_1} \oplus T_{s,k_2} \dots   \oplus T_{s,k_n}}) \subset \mathbb{T}^n\\ 
\{k_{1}, k_{2}\dots k_{n} \}\subset\{1,2\dots s\}$$

For any two points $p_{1} =  (z_{1,1},z_{2,1} \cdots z_{n,1}) $ and  $p_{2} =  (z_{1,2},z_{2,2} \cdots z_{n,2}) $ situated in the same region we will have $z_{i,1}, z_{i,2} \in \mathbb{T}_{s,k_i}$ thus $|z_{i,1} - z_{i,2}| < \frac{2\pi}{s}$ for all $i \in \{1,2\cdots n \}$ .

By considering the isomorphism $\mathbb{T} \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ the regions described above could be considered analogous to splitting an $n$-dimensional cube of segment $1$ into $s^n$ disjoint smaller cubes of segment $1/s$.

For the final part of the proof, consider a point $p\in \mathbb{T}^m$ given by $p = (z_{1},z_{2} \dots z_{n})$. By the pigeonhole principle, out of the elements $p^1, p^2\dots p^{s^n+1}$ (where $p^k = (z_1^k,z_2^k \dots z_{n}^k)$), at least two points $p^{k_{1}}$, $p^{k_{2}}$ with  $k_1$ < $k_2$ will fall in the same region, as we have $s^n$ regions and $s^{n}+1$ elements. From this we have   $|z_{i}^{k_{2}} - z_{i}^{k_{1}}| < \frac{2\pi}{s}$ and $|z_{i}^{k_{2}-k_{1}} - 1| < \frac{2\pi}{s}$ for all $i$ in $\{1 \dots n \}$.  Thus we can set $m = k_{2}-k_{1}$.

As we can make $s$ arbitrarily large, we can make $\varepsilon = \frac{2\pi}{s}$ arbitrarily small, and the problem is solved.